# How to iterate a cursor in mongodb using python?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

**My document structure is something like this....**

[image]

**I ran this query**

```
test_run_names = self._database.suiteruns.find({'user': user_id, {'$or': [{'name': {'$exists': True}},{'name': {'$eq': ""}}]}})
```

***test_run_names is of type cursor.***

How can i iterate over it and get the attributes i need ?

> *What i did ?*

```
for t in test_run_names 
    print (t['name']) #throws a key error
```

Comment: I'd suggest to have a look at https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have an element without name.

Try this instead:

```
for t in test_run_names 
    print (t.get('name'))
```

Comment: Ok, i am trying it out, but isnt t['name'] same as t.get('name') ?

Comment: t['name'] will throw an error if name doesn't exist and t.get('name') will return none if there's no name variable

Comment: I mean, it will throw an error if name is not defined

Comment: Every get('name') shows none , why is that ? Do i need to put projection too ? I mean cursor is returning only the object id i suppose. So that is why maybe every get operation returns None . Am i right ? If yes , how do i get other attributes ?

Comment: Maybe you do have none in every document. You can print t just to make sure the data you are getting makes sense.

Comment: printing t gives only the objectID, maybe i need to add a projection with name:1 , Right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113481/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-juanin).